# Индексы в обновлении весов

Tags: python, машинное-обучение, нейронные-сети

В бумагах на arxiv и некоторых видео, функция обновления весов выглядит как

[image: формула обновления весов]

И в других методах оптимизации индексы такие же. Почему так и как правильно это читать?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Индекс означает буквально "значение на шаге таком то". Т.е. формула описывает, каким образом вес на следующем шаге (`t`) алгоритма обновления зависит от веса на предыдущем шаге `t-1` и производную ошибки .